# Issues ordering items from the HHA

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

How long does it usually take for HHA orders to reach your mailbox?

I ordered two items the other day at around 1-2am and they arrived almost instantly, but the last two days have ordered items around 9am-12pm and they only arrive the next day.

Answer (score 2):

Mail deliveries from HHA and the catalogue are at 9AM and 5PM. If your mailbox was full, you won't receive your items until the next scheduled delivery.

Answer (score 2):

What Spectro said it's true. I always receive them the next day or at 5pm that very same day if I bought them that morning early.

Remember if you're playing with time (time traveling / date changing and such) the mail man will be affected and will come at random times, some days he won't even come at all.

Comment: I haven't done any time travel. I just think it's weird that the first time I ordered from the HHA it arrived instantly, but all subsequent times they only arrive the next day. :\